# Stack Rank change notification not working in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I want to get an Email whenever the Stack Rank of a Work Item in Azure Devops changes. I set the notification up like this:

[image: Azure Devops Notification]

However, it does not seem to be working. I do not get an Email when the Stack Rank of a Work Item changes.

I do get Emails when I set up the notification to listen for changes of other fields. Only the Stack Rank change notification does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Can the answer can help you solve the puzzle about why field Stack Rank does not has useful? Don't hesitate to share us your more puzzle:-)

Answer (score 0):

You did not miss anything.

Just this feature does be supported until now. But the Microsoft product group are evaluating it for future releases, but due to sparsification of the other work items, its state is lower Priority. I believe it will be released in the future. You can check and follow this DC ticket which has been report by other user recently: [No notification about stack rank changes](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85477/no-notification-about-stack-rank-changes.html).